# Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "AIRMap" was not found in the UIManager

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I followed the instruction in the documentation for installing **react-native-maps**. I also tried every answer I could find online, ranging from adding: *new MapsPackage();*  and *import com.airbnb.android.react.maps.MapsPackage;* to manually linking the library.
The former stopped my emulator running, while the later didn't cause a difference.

I've tried every solution my hands can find, and still no answer. I'll be glad if someone can help me fix this.

**N/B: This works perfectly on iOS, but not on android**.

Below is what my code looks like:

```
<MapView
       provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE} 
       style={styles.map}
       region={{
         latitude: params.latitude,
         longitude:params.longitude,
         latitudeDelta: 0.015,
         longitudeDelta: 0.0121,
       }}
     >
        <Marker coordinate={{ latitude:params.latitude, longitude: params.longitude }}
        pinColor={colors.orange}
        > 
        </Marker>
     </MapView>
```